# connecting to a ssh server using server's ssh private key only

Tags: networking, ssh, security

for a CTF challenge design contest, I am looking for a way to enable connecting to the server using server's ssh private key only, I have tried out different ways to enable participants to connect to the server by having the server's ssh private key, but each time I try connecting I will be prompted to enter password, thanks a lot for helping me solve this problem.

I have been using the following command to connect to the ssh server:

ssh -i server_privatekey @<server_ip>

Comment: What do you mean by "server's ssh private key", exactly? Do you mean the one from /etc/ssh?

Comment: on server a pair of keys are generated in ~/.ssh folder e.g. id_rsa and id_rsa.pub , and throughout challenge,participants will read the id_rsa file from the server, now I want them to be able to use this private key file to connect to server with ssh without being prompted for password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> on server a pair of keys are generated in ~/.ssh folder e.g. id_rsa and id_rsa.pub , and throughout challenge,participants will read the id_rsa file from the server, now I want them to be able to use this private key file to connect to server with ssh without being prompted for password

Like with any other use of SSH keypairs, the public key (i.e. contents of id_rsa.pub) **must** be added to the server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for that account (or possibly to some other file that's configured as AuthorizedKeysFile on the server).

That is, there is no such thing as "server's ssh private key" in this situation. It does not matter *where* the key was generated – being generated on the server does not make it special; it still needs to be listed in the authorized_keys file one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for
[Create a public SSH key from the private key?](https://serverfault.com/questions/52285/create-a-public-ssh-key-from-the-private-key)

The accepted answer says this :

> Use the -y option to ssh-keygen:
>
> ```
> ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -y > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
> ```
>
> From the 'man ssh-keygen'
>
> ```
>  -y      This option will read a private OpenSSH format file and print an
>          OpenSSH public key to stdout.
> ```
>
> Specify the private key with the -f option, yours might be dsa instead
> of rsa.  The name of your private key probably contains which you
> used.  The newly generated public key should be the same as the one
> you generated before.